# JavaScript function not being invoked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to invoke a script function on my MVC view as follows,
but it's not happening. What may be the reason behind it?

```
<input type="text" id="hdnTemp" value="xyz" onload="test();" />                    
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      function test() {
                        alert();
                      }
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`input` elements do not have an `onload` event.

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3)

> The onload event occurs when the user agent finishes loading a window or all frames within a FRAMESET. This attribute may be used with BODY and FRAMESET elements.

You could use the `body`'s `onload` event, or another event in your input like `onclick` or `onchange`, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The [input](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_input.asp) tag doesn't have the onload event.

Answer (score 1):

The onload event is only for body and frameset elements. See here for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#events .

If you want the function to execute after the page loads, you can use
`<body onload="test();">`.

If you want to execute it after the user types something, you can use
`<input ... onchange="test();">`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked in Javascript, but I'm pretty sure you have to declare the function before calling it. So, your 'onload()' doesn't know what it's calling.